# Concatenate non empty CONCAT_GROUP to parent column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

I need to get the list of categories from store_cat, with the child `COUNT` from store_item (amount of products) and `GROUP_CONCAT` from store_cat_attributes (list of attributes). The thing is, using `CONCAT` function I need to attach the `GROUP_CONCAT` value with `name` column in the parent table (store_cat), and that's where it gets tricky.

This works fine:

```
SELECT
    store_cat.id_cat AS id,
    store_cat.name AS name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(store_cat_attribute.name SEPARATOR ", ") AS attributes,
    COUNT(store_item.id_item) AS products,
    store_cat.flg_public AS flg_public
FROM store_cat
LEFT JOIN store_item ON store_item.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat
LEFT JOIN store_cat_attribute ON store_cat_attribute.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat
WHERE store_cat.id_store = 1
GROUP BY store_cat.id_cat
ORDER BY name
```

But this is what I would actually need. The problem is that, when I execute this query, the store_cat.name value shows an **empty** value when there are no attributes:

```
SELECT
    store_cat.id_cat AS id,
    CONCAT(store_cat.name, " (", GROUP_CONCAT(store_cat_attribute.name SEPARATOR ", "), ")") AS name,
    COUNT(store_item.id_item) AS products,
    store_cat.flg_public AS flg_public
FROM store_cat
LEFT JOIN store_item ON store_item.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat
LEFT JOIN store_cat_attribute ON store_cat_attribute.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat
WHERE store_cat.id_store = 1
GROUP BY store_cat.id_cat ORDER BY name
```

Basically, the idea is that the `store_cat.name` column should contain the attributes list with `CONCAT` and `GROUP_CONCAT`, just like this:

- Comidas
- Correas (S, M, L, XL)
- Juguetes
- Medicinas

Here's the current [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8b6fef/4). By the way, something is off with the attributes order in the current `GROUP_CONCAT`. It is displaying (**XL**, S, M, L) instead of (S, M, L, **XL**).

Problems to solve:

1. Use `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate the attributes to the category name only when there are attributes.
2. Use the `store_cat_attributes.position` to set the order for the `GROUP_CONCAT` values.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  following expression should return the results that you expect :

```
CONCAT(
    store_cat.name,
    IFNULL(
        CONCAT(
            ' (', 
            GROUP_CONCAT(
                store_cat_attribute.name 
                ORDER BY store_cat_attribute.position 
                SEPARATOR ', '
             ),
            ')'
        ),
        ''
    )
) AS name
```

Basically, this just tries to `GROUP_CONCAT()` the attributes, and if the result is `NULL` then it turns the attribute list to an empty string. Please note that `GROUP_CONCAT` support `ORDER BY`.

I also fixed the `GROUP BY` clause : in non-ancient versions of MySQL, all non-aggregared columns must appear in the where clause (you are missing `store_cat.name`).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ej9rdrgsmACpnqZQXcxs86/1)** with your sample data :

```
SELECT 
    store_cat.id_cat AS id,
    CONCAT(
        store_cat.name,
        IFNULL(
            CONCAT(
                ' (', 
                GROUP_CONCAT(store_cat_attribute.name ORDER BY store_cat_attribute.position SEPARATOR ', '),
                ')'
            ),
            ''
        )
    ) AS name, 

    COUNT(store_item.id_item) AS products, 
    store_cat.flg_public AS flg_public 
FROM 
    store_cat 
    LEFT JOIN store_item ON store_item.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat 
    LEFT JOIN store_cat_attribute ON store_cat_attribute.id_cat = store_cat.id_cat 
WHERE store_cat.id_store = 1 
GROUP BY store_cat.id_cat, store_cat.name
ORDER BY name;
```

```
| id  | flg_public | name                  | products |
| --- | ---------- | --------------------- | -------- |
| 3   | 1          | Comidas               | 0        |
| 2   | 1          | Correas (S, M, L, XL) | 4        |
| 1   | 1          | Juguetes              | 2        |
| 4   |            | Medicinas             | 0        |
```

Comment: one quick question though, if my server uses MySQL 5.6+, is it also necessary to group by `store_cat.name`?

Comment: @AndresSK : actually no. MySQL implemented it in version 5.7.5, but this is a good practice in SQL that you should get familiar with. See [this link](https://medium.com/@riccardoodone/the-love-hate-relationship-between-select-and-group-by-in-sql-4957b2a70229) for more context.

Comment: so sorry, but i just noticed something wrong in the results. The products in the `id_cat=2` (**Correas**) row, should be **1**, but it is displaying **4**... after some tests i found out that the products count is displaying the number of `store_cat_attribute` records (instead of number of `store_item` records) when attributes are present.

Comment: @AndresSK : mm ok, I think that you should be able to solve this by changing `COUNT(store_item.id_item)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT store_item.id_item)` : see **[this updated db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ej9rdrgsmACpnqZQXcxs86/2)**.